# After upgrading to iTunes 11, I cannot see my iPad mini

Tags: macos, itunes, data-synchronization, file-sharing

I'd like to access my iPad mini file sharing via iTunes 11. However, I cannot see the iPad mini on the left hand Sidebar (View > Show Sidebar).

I also pulled out and re-inserted the USB cable a few times, quitted and restart iTunes 11 a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The USB process that talks to iOS devices starts at system boot (or installation of iTunes) and not with the quit/restart of the app.

If you don't have a connection after restarting your Mac, you can download and run the iTunes installer again to see if the helper didn't get installed or started correctly.

Apple has a very nice assistant to work through common errors, so rather than my guess, you could also just follow that and be systematic about ruling out the common causes of this.

- http://www.apple.com/support/ipad/assistant/itunes/

It will get you to perform both the reboot and re-install, but might solve the issue in less time. Happy troubleshooting.